# LS command not listing files in Amazon EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ls

I'm using an Amazon ec2 instance and am SSHed into it. For some reason when I use the ls command, it doesn't list the files in the current directory. Is this command disabled by default? if so, is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was that I was in the ~ folder. Once I cd into the html folder, i was able to list the files. Could also be a permissions thing because i have permissions in the html folder